# Generating Lots of Thumbnails Using Imagick

Tags: php, imagick

When I'm generating thumbnails using Imagick, I load the image once, using:

`$im = new Imagick( $filePath );`

Then I pass this `$im` object around to create different sizes using

```
 $im->thumbnailImage($newX, $newY);
```

However, I've observed, that when I use the same `$im` Image Resource, the quality of the image blobs isn't as good as if I read the file again and start from fresh by opening the file again.

This makes me think, that perhaps I should be doing something after I do a `thumbnailImage()` in order to reset it back to the original file resource?

Additionally, after I do a cropImage() I cannot get the `$im` back to the original image. 
I have tried using `$im->setImagePage(0, 0, 0, 0);` without any luck.

Is there something I should be doing instead of using thumbnailImage to get he best quality?

Futhermore, if the original image is 32kb, the `$im` when I finally write it, is like 90kb.

Answer (score 0):

You must [clone](https://www.php.net/clone) your object before doing a thumbnail:

```
$im_thumb = clone $im;
```

To create images with low size uses [setCompressionQuality](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setcompressionquality.php) method, normally 60 or 70 makes the job.

(many samples in PHP links above)

I usually have faster results using the GD library, many instructions/samples to resize [here](http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php)